# AWS Signing request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-chime

I'm using amazon chime js sdk for generating pre-signed URL for connecting to the chime websocket. When I use *new WebSocket()* in js, everything works well: connection gets connected, session gets started, etc. But when I'm trying open the link via postman, or an addon for Chrome, or via JAVA, it drops the connection immediately, and the response is just "4401 UNAUTHORIZED", despite the fact that URL is 100% correct.

Can somebody consult me about this?

Might it be rejected, if the user-agent in URL, and in request is different?

P.S. Sorry if my explanation is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote fully working [code](https://github.com/i-soroka/amazon-presigned-url-for-amazon-chime-websocket/blob/main/DefaultSigV4.java) for signing URL in JAVA. Hope this will help somebody!

Comment: Hi can where was the problem and how you fixed it, currently i am facing the same issue.